# Get specific JSON data from sql query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I would like to say thank you for reading this question.

And my question is. I have this php code with sql query:

```
mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_login, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

$req = "SELECT name, elements "
."FROM lwzax_zoo_item "
."WHERE application_id = '2' AND elements LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' ";

$query = mysql_query($req);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name'], 'desc' => $row['elements']);
}


$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```

And output is:

```
[  
 {  
  "label":"0146T",
  "desc":" {\n\t\"cec36dd6-ffde-494d-b25c-8e58bff84e22\": {\n\t\t\"0\":        {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Ccta W\\/Wo Dye\"\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}"
 },
 {  
  "label":"64653",
  "desc":" {\n\t\"cec36dd6-ffde-494d-b25c-8e58bff84e22\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Chemodenervation Eccrine Glands Oth Area Per Day\"\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}"
 }
]
```

But I need only label data and value data...so it should look like:

```
[  
 {  
  "label":"0146T",
  "desc":"Ccta W\\/Wo Dye"
 },
 {  
  "label":"64653",
  "desc":"Chemodenervation Eccrine Glands Oth Area Per Day"
 }
]
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you very much for help

UPDATE: Deleted $b = json_decode($row['desc'], true); as it wasn't used, just a junk from all my attempts to succeed.

Comment: BTW: This `'%".$_REQUEST['term']."%'` is a huge security problem...

Comment: you're storing json-in-json-in-json-in-json ad nauseum? If you want your `desc` to be simpler, then you'd need to decode it hoever many times you ENcoded it, and extract only the bits you want.

Comment: Actually that $b = json_decode($row['elements']); is of no use. I forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're decoding the JSON and assigning it to `$b`, but you're not doing anything with that variable. Use:

```
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name'],
                       'desc' => $b['cec36dd6-ffde-494d-b25c-8e58bff84e22'][0]['value']);
```

Also, you need to give a second argument to `json_decode`, so it will return an associative array rather than an object.

```
$b = json_decode($row['elements'], true);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions.
So If I understand correctly, I changed it as you suggested but now I am getting: [{"label":"0146T","desc":null},{"label":"0148T","desc":null}

Comment: I wonder if that long code is always the same. If not, you'll probably have to write a loop that goes through `$b`.

Comment: Yes, cec36dd6-ffde-494d-b25c-8e58bff84e22 is always same

Comment: Ooops, `$row['desc']` should be `$row['elements']` in the `json_decode()` call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, first things first, initialize your array OUTSIDE your loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $b = json_decode($row['elements']);
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name'], 'desc' => $row['elements']);
}
```

Then you should probably do this:

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $b = json_decode($row['elements']);
    array_push($results, array('label' => $row['name'], 'desc' => json_decode($row['elements'], true));
}
```

The at the end

```
$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. But every time I add $results = array(); I get only [].
And even without this I am getting same as before :(

Comment: I think $row['elements'] might be undefined for some reason. Look into that and if you need to, do a var_dump($row) to see what everything is.
Edit - Also, just realized that results[] works just fine, don't worry about initializing outside the loop.

Comment: When I try to use  echo $row['elements']; inside loop I get results, so probably must be defined.